# save webpage as a url file and open with chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

How can I simply save a webpage in chrome as a text based url file that when clicked in finder opens the webpage in chrome?

Here is what I have so far found and tried: the following code:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://http://stackoverflow.com/
```

(it needs an empty line at the end too but I couldn't get that shown in the code above). When saved as a .url file and kept simply in my filesystem, and click on it it opens the webpage directly in safari (since I am on a mac with osx). I want this to open in Chrome, but changing the "open with" settings opens the file as a text file; it doesn't execute and take me to that webpage.

Comment: Have you set chrome as [default browser](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95417)?

Comment: Yes. Even so, when I click .url files they come up in safari. So I set that all .url files to be opened in chrome. Now they do; but as text.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was in your exact same situation Geoff, and I was able to find this after digging through a ton of forums.

1. Open up Chrome/Firefox and go to the web page you were wanting to save.
2. Look at the address bar.
3. Find the [padlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS#Browser_integration) icon that is just to the left of your URL string. It may look like a page, or a lock, or a lock with a yellow triangle.
4. Click and drag it to the Desktop and then drop it.

This will create a webloc file, and for me it shows a Safari icon as the file image, even says Safari is the default program to open it.  However, when I click on it, it always opens up in Chrome! :)

Hope this helps.

Using Chrome Version 29.0.1547.76

OSX 10.9.2

Comment: this is unexpected

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768604/10258377

Thank you @AZRckCrwler.

I would like to make it easier to understand base on his answer.

> Find the padlock icon that is just to the left of your URL string. It may look like a page, or a lock, or a lock with a yellow triangle.

You can see the circle that I marked, then drag & drop here.

[image]